# Creating xlsx file

Tags: c#, .net, excel, xlsx

I am basically creating a xlsx file but I am getting an error while using that file like below.

> System.IO.FileFormatException: Archive file cannot be size 0.

The way I tried.

```
string file = "c:\\DoneDone61.xlsx";

using(File.Create(file))
{

}
```

Also I cannot open excel file manually because it says the file is corrupted.

Thanks for answers in advance.

Comment: First, you are trying to create a file in the root directory of disk C: and this is could be a problem. Second  you don't show the lines where the exception occurs. Third, just because you create a file with xlsx extension, does not mean that it is valid for excel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An Excel file which you consider to be "blank" is not just a file with no data in it (which is what you are creating). You can see this yourself by creating a document manually in Excel and then opening it in notepad. You'll notice that it actually has data inside of it. That data is used to store information regarding the three empty sheets named "Sheet1", "Sheet2" and "Sheet3". Also, there is some header information so that any program looking at the file knows that it is actually a compressed file (as per the Excel file format). So, as you can see, even a pretty empty excel file still contains SOME data.

If you want to create a blank excel document using C#, you have two good options:

1. Use a library that allows you to actually work with creating Excel documents that takes care of creating the file correctly. Check out something like the [Microsoft OpenXML SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5124) or [ExcelPackage](http://excelpackage.codeplex.com/).
2. Create an empty Excel document, store it somewhere, and when you want to "create" a new empty Excel document, just make a copy of this file.

Answer (score 1):

This one ...

```
using(File.Create(filePath))
{
}
```

... creates an empty file. Read: *really empty (=> 0 bytes*)  not an empty XLSX with an XLSX skeleton: ZIP container, file header, style definitions, ....

What exactly did you expect?

**EDIT:**
If you want to create an empty XLSX file (like "Right Click on Mouse > New > New Microsoft Excel"), you have to use such an template, ... and write it onto the disk.

To achieve that, you have to deploy this template file with your application, and then do a `File.Copy(source, dest)`, or integrate it as a *resource* and write the resource content to the disk.

Comment: I am excepting to create a empty excel sheet in it like when we create a new excel sheet on windows. Such as Right Click on Mouse > New > New Microsoft Excel Worksheet. But I guess now, I should do sth more for it

Answer (score 1):

What you need to use is [Interop.Excel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel%28v=office.11%29.aspx) namespace. Here's a guide from [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173186%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

please use this...Its a bit hacky but couldn't get a better way to do this using InterOp

```
   public static void CreateEmptyXLSXFile(string FilePath)
    {
        FileStream MyStream = new FileStream(FilePath, FileMode.CreateNew,     FileAccess.ReadWrite);
        MyStream.Write(ExcelDocumentsInterOps.GetEmptyXSLXFileBytes(), 0, ExcelDocumentsInterOps.GetEmptyXSLXFileBytes().Length);
        MyStream.Flush();
        MyStream.Close();
        MyStream.Dispose();
        MyStream = null;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the bytes for an empty xslx file
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static byte[] GetEmptyXSLXFileBytes()
    {
        string TheSting = "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";
        return Convert.FromBase64String(TheSting);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with spreadsheet related tasks in .NET, you can use this *open source library* called [SpreadsheetLight](http://www.nuget.org/packages/SpreadsheetLight/) to write an excel file (especially, if you want to write content at some point).

If you prefer adding it as package [via Nuget](http://www.nuget.org/packages/SpreadsheetLight/), you can say:

> Install-Package SpreadsheetLight

After that, going by [GenerateReport() exmaple](http://spreadsheetlight.com/sample-code/):

```
// this one creates an empty workbook
using (SLDocument sl = new SLDocument())
{
    // sl.SetCellValue("B3", "I love ASP.NET MVC");
    sl.SaveAs("c:\\DoneDone61.xlsx");
}
```

Also see their [tutorial](http://spreadsheetlight.com/tutorial/) for more interesting stuff.